# Get N Rows from Value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of monthly sales numbers for events. I have a column `Event_Ind` that indicates whether that month had an event. I need to get the 3 values (inclusive) prior to each event. Values are allowed to overlap.

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', end='2020-01-01', freq='M')
values = [1000,1067,1099,1100,2000,1000,1057,1082,1200,1300,1453,1500]
event_ind = ["*","","","","*","","","","*","","*",""]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates':dates, 'Values':values, 'Event_Ind':event_ind})


        Dates  Values Event_Ind
0  2019-01-31    1000         *
1  2019-02-28    1067          
2  2019-03-31    1099          
3  2019-04-30    1100          
4  2019-05-31    2000         *
5  2019-06-30    1000          
6  2019-07-31    1057          
7  2019-08-31    1082          
8  2019-09-30    1200         *
9  2019-10-31    1300          
10 2019-11-30    1453         *
11 2019-12-31    1500
```

Goal would be for this sample data:

```
    Dates   Values  Event_Ind
0   1/31/2019   1000    *
1   3/31/2019   1099    
2   4/30/2019   1100    
3   5/31/2019   2000    *
4   7/31/2019   1057    
5   8/31/2019   1082    
6   9/30/2019   1200    *
7   9/30/2019   1200    *
8   10/31/2019  1300    
9   11/30/2019  1453    *
```

I'm thinking I can do something with [`shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) or [`groupby.tail()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html). But I can't seem to use them to get my desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could something along these lines:

```
s = df.Event_Ind.eq('*')
i = np.concatenate([np.arange(a,b+1) for b,a in zip(s[s].index, s[s].index - 2)])
```

```
df.loc[i[i>=0]]
```

---

```
        Dates  Values Event_Ind
0  2019-01-31    1000         *
1  2019-02-28    1067          
2  2019-03-31    1099          
3  2019-04-30    1100          
4  2019-05-31    2000         *
5  2019-06-30    1000          
6  2019-07-31    1057          
7  2019-08-31    1082          
8  2019-09-30    1200         *
7  2019-08-31    1082          
8  2019-09-30    1200         *
9  2019-10-31    1300          
10 2019-11-30    1453         *
```

---

Explanation

```
[np.arange(a,b+1) for b,a in zip(s[s].index, s[s].index - 2)]
```

The above code `zip`s the indexes values with `*` with indexes two rows above. Thus, `np.arange(a,b+1)` yields the indexes of rows you want to show at the final `df`.

Since the above generates a list of arrays, you want to `np.concatenate` all that to have a single array of indexes to keep.

```
df.loc[i[i>=0]]
```

Finally, the above first filters all values in `i` that are negative (because negative indexes in python have a meaning) and `df.loc[]` that to retrieve the final df.

Comment: I like the idea! I had a similar thought. Unfortunately, this implementation does not give me the expected result

Comment: @MattR make sure to play with the arguments in `zip`. Not sure if you want `index, index-3` or `index, index-2` etc

Comment: Changing it to -2 gave me desired result! Would you be able to break down or comment on the code of what that beautiful one liner is doing? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x=df["Event_Ind"]=="*"
ind=list(map(lambda i: any(x[i:i+3]), range(len(x))))
print(df.loc[ind])
```

Output:

```py
Dates  Values Event_Ind
0  2019-01-31    1000         *
2  2019-03-31    1099
3  2019-04-30    1100
4  2019-05-31    2000         *
6  2019-07-31    1057
7  2019-08-31    1082
8  2019-09-30    1200         *
9  2019-10-31    1300
10 2019-11-30    1453         *

[Program finished]
```

Comment: This works, except it does not pick up the "duplicate" at `2019-09-30`. May have to find out how to add that

Comment: Hm, but what is the logic for this duplication on your side? I.e. I just realized it's in the desired output, but I don't see the logic behind it appearing there

Comment: on `2019-09-30` there is a `*` so it gets a record there. there is also a `*` on `2019-11-30` and since I need the two before it, it grabs the `2019-09-30` record again